# Is there a Mac OS X terminal application which will autocomplete commands available within a program?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal, autocomplete

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I've done some searching and haven't been able to find anything.

I have recently installed Fedora 23 and I've noticed the terminal application does auto-complete of commands within a program. An example would be:

```
$ git com[tab]
```

and it will autocomplete to

```
$ git commit
```

It even works for flagged commands which take argument. Suppose I have some program which takes the flag `-c` and accepts either `yes` or `no`. I could also do:

```
$ some_program -c y[tab]
```

and the autocomplete would give

```
$ some_program -c yes
```

Does anyone know if there is a terminal application or something similar for Mac OS X?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the terminal emulator you are using. it depends on the shell. In `bash`, the default shell in both OSX and Fedora, this behavior is controlled by `bash_completion`. See the suggested duplicate for how to get the same functionality on a mac.